# Line graph with ggplot2 in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to learn the R programming language to analyse and visualize my data. I have made some good progress so far and I am really enjoying learning R but I am stomped here.

I am having some trouble creating line graphs for products in specific categories. I have no problem creating graphs to show sales all categories but I would like to specify a particular category and show the **product** sales.

[This is what my data set looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh6OK.png)

Can someone show me how I could do this? E.g I would like to create a **line** graph to show the sales of Products in the **Bakery** category where the **X** axis would have the product name and the **Y** axis would have the quantity sold.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. People are downvoting because you give a picture instead of actual data to work with. please give a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve using dput() on your data or head(). You need to learn how to subset your data with a condition in order to have the particular category (plenty of way and answer in this forum)

Comment: Hi @denis what would be the best way for me to upload my data to this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see the answers to "[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)". In particular, using `dput` or `head` to provide data in a copyable way is much better than images of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please include the head this can be done using

```
head(Store_sales)

  ProductID      category sales                  product
1       101        Bakery  9468              White bread
2       102 Personal Care  9390 Everday Female deodorant
3       103        Cereal  9372                 Weetabix
4       104       Produce  9276                    Apple
5       105          Meat  9268          Chicken Breasts
6       106        Bakery  9252                Pankcakes
```

I reproduced relevant fields to help you out. First thing is to filter out Baker items from categories.

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
> library(tidyverse)
```

Store sales before filter

```
> Store_sales
  ProductID      category sales                  product
1       101        Bakery  9468              White bread
2       102 Personal Care  9390 Everday Female deodorant
3       103        Cereal  9372                 Weetabix
4       104       Produce  9276                    Apple
5       105          Meat  9268          Chicken Breasts
6       106        Bakery  9252                Pankcakes
7       107       Produce  9228                   Carrot
```

Filter out "Bakery" from category column into Store_sales_bakery

```
> Store_sales_bakery <- filter(Store_sales, category == "Bakery")
```

What Store_sales_bakery includes

```
> Store_sales_bakery
  ProductID category sales     product
1       101   Bakery  9468 White bread
2       106   Bakery  9252   Pankcakes
```

Unfortunately because the picture you gave us does not contain enough information to produce a line graph (you only have 1 data point for each variable which is not enough to create a line) so in its stead I created a point plot for you.

```
ggplot(Store_sales, aes(x = product, y = sales)) + geom_point()
```

[ggplot point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6rPn.png)

Here is a bar plot with two variables

```
ggplot(Store_sales, aes(x = product, y = sales)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS4Iw.png)

If you had enough data to make a line graph you would replace geom_bar() or geom_point() with geom_line()

Here is a link to ggplot cheatsheet that may help you in the future

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf